# Input function not working in Python Code

Tags: python, input

I was writing a python code in VS Code and somehow it's not detecting the input() function like it should.
Suppose, the code is as simple as

```
def main():    
    x= int ( input() )
    print(x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

even then, for some reason it is throwing error and I cannot figure out why.
The error being-
[image]

P.S. 1)I am using Python 3.10 2) I tried removing the int() and it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's because the input value cannot be converted to int

Comment: what are you giving as the input?

Comment: Hello @ramzeek , the prompt for the input did not come. Before that it is throwing the error.

Comment: I ran your code, and it works. If you enter a number, it prints the number but if you enter a string of characters, you get a `ValueError`. There is no prompt for input because you have `input()` but the shell is waiting for input. If you write something like `input('need input:> ')` then you should see the input prompt.

Answer (score 1):

The traceback shows you where to look. It's actually the `int` function throwing a `ValueError`. It looks as if you're feeding it a filepath whereas it it's expecting a number.

You could add a check to repeat the input if incorrect like so:

```py
user_input = None
while not user_input:
    raw_input = input("Put in a number: ")    
    try:
        user_input = int(raw_input)
    except ValueError:
        continue

print(f"Number is: {user_input}")
```

Answer (score 0):

it's working!!!

see my example that says why you don't understand this:

```py
>>> x1 = input('enter a number: ')
enter a number: 10
>>> x1
'10'
>>> x2 = int(x1)
>>> x2
10
>>> x1 = input()  # no text
100
>>> # it takes
>>> x1
'100'
>>> # but how you try?
>>> x1 = input()
NOT-NUMBER OR EMPTY-TEXT
>>> x2 = int(x1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'IS-NOT-NUMBER OR EMPTY TEXT'
>>>
```

I thing this is enough.

Comment: Thanks @Delta , now I see that input is working for me too. However, when I try to type cast the input into int, the problem comes.

Comment: @KaraageAndKamehameha
So now two questions arise: what exactly is the problem? How is it solved? If my guess is correct, this is not the place for your question. However, I hope you succeed in any way you can

Answer (score 0):

The int() func is try to convert your string to Integer so it should be just numbers. It seems you are giving number and characters as an input so it raise the Value Error. if you want you can check if it is just numbers or not

```
x = input()
if x.isdigit():
   x = int(x)
```